# Searching for a model like ZIP, but to model three data-generating processes, not just two

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, zero-inflation

What type of test would fit my data in this situation?

I'm measuring a count variable. Like in a zero-inflated poisson, I have numerous observations that are zeros because of a separate process. But I also have observations that have extremely high outcomes in the count variable because of a distinct process.

Can I model a "zero-inflated & high-outcome inflated" poisson or something like it?

Comment: A negative binomial count model might help - it's a little more flexible than the Poisson model. http://ehs.sph.berkeley.edu/hubbard/longdata/webfiles/poissonmarch2005.pdf

Comment: How about a finite mixture model with 3 types?